# Solution(s?) of the functional equation $f(2f(x)) = 2x$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

I want to prove that the only solution of $f(2f(X)) = 2X$
is $f(X) = X.$

I tried doing it like this:

- If $f(X) > X$ then $ f(2f(X)) > 2X$
- If $f(X) < X$ then $f(2f(X)) < 2x$
- Hence $f(X)$ must be equal to $X$.

I got told we cannot do this but didn't fully understand why not? Can somebody explain ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For problems like this you have to specify the domain and codomain of the function and whether or not it's supposed to have any special properties like for example continuity or differentiability, otherwise you usually get (infinitely) many extraneous solutions that you weren't looking for. In this example if we assume that the domain and codomain are the real numbers, then we get infinitely many other solutions, one of them being $-x^2$ for nonnegative $x$ and $\sqrt{2|x|}$ for negative $x$.

Comment: You cannot do this because $f(x)$ may $>x$ for some $x$'s and $<x$ for other $x$'s.

Comment: The so-called pointwise trap!